# How to get link button text and value in datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have an ajaxtabcontainer control in my project which contains a datalist and in datalist, I have set the names as a link button. The datalist that I am binding to a source is containing Names and age. Now I want to use the age as a selected value as we use in dropdownlist selected value? what I want is on clicking the name link button I get its value inside a label? how to do it? what I have done is as follows:
in Default aspx:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1">
            <HeaderTemplate>
               Names
            </HeaderTemplate>
         <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5" ForeColor="Red"  
            RepeatLayout="Table" >

              <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton Text = '<%#Eval("names")%>' ID="lnkpro" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" OnClick="btn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>

        </ContentTemplate>

    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

in cs code:

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LinkButton myButton = sender as LinkButton;
        if (myButton != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = myButton.Text;
        }

    }
    protected void datalist1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.ItemIndex);
        LinkButton lnkid = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkpro");
        Label1.Text = lnkid.Text;
        i = Convert.ToInt32(lnkid.Text);
    }
```

but they are not working. the btn_click is working but giving the only name not its id. the second datalist_itemcommand is not working? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you did not have OnItemCommand="datalist1_ItemCommand" in the aspx page.  datalist1_ItemCommand should fire after you set OnItemCommand property.

```
  <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5" ForeColor="Red"   OnItemCommand="datalist1_ItemCommand"
            RepeatLayout="Table" DataKeyField="age" >
              <ItemTemplate>                  
              <asp:LinkButton Text = '<%#Eval("names")%>' ID="lnkpro" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" OnClick="btn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

If you are trying to get the age field value in the datalist1_itemCommand function, you need to set DataKeyFeild= "age". And in the item command function you can do Convert.ToInt32(DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]) to get the value. Your item Command function will be

```
   protected void datalist1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int age = Convert.ToInt32(DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]);
    }
```